# How do I completely Uninstall Flutter SDK from Windows

Tags: windows, flutter

How do I completely uninstall Flutter SDK from Windows?
I tried to delete the Flutter Folder I had cloned from GitHub but that's not working for some reason.

Comment: What does *that's not working* mean specifically?

Answer (score 8):

Go to C drive and delete flutter folder completely, if it shows that it Opened in some app, then just restart the device and delete the folder again, it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You have to delete flutter extension in Android Studio if you installed it, then, check envirment variables then you removes paths if exists. Finally, kill adb.exe if it's running (this may blocks you in removing folder)

Comment: Don't know much about Studio but also I would do some kind of backup of virtual devices and remove them, re-creating  environments when necessary; don't judge me, I think I'm paranoid.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I followed [C. Khalifa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1229031/c-khalifa) steps, but still not working for me. It says another program is still using it. My final step was restarting my windows in Safe Mode, then I could delete it completely. Hopefully, someone can try this if they are still not able to delete the folder.

Answer (score -2):

If you go to the dir where you cloned dir and delete it. That should remove the command line tool.

`rm -rf flutter`

`re-install git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable`

Answer (score -6):

Uninstall Flutter with its uninstaller.exe.

to do that

a. Go to the installation folder of Flutter.

b. Find uninstall.exe or unins000.exe.

c. double click and run it.

Comment: Can't find that file.

Comment: same ..they no longer have this file in their latest vaersions