# How to clear flutter deps and packages cache?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, package-management

My vs code came up with a "get packages" button and I mistakenly pressed it.

[image: such help]

Now even though my packages are pinned (one in particular) at a certain version, it always tries to run the project with the latest version, which gives me errors like this:

```
/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serverpod_serialization-0.9.20/lib/src/serialization.dart:21:11: Context: 'SerializableEntity.toJson' is defined here.
```

Notice it is referencing `serverpod_serialization-0.9.20`

I have all my `serverpod` stuff pinned at `^0.9.8`

I've tried stuff like this: [How to remove or identify unused packages from flutter to reduce size of the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926787/how-to-remove-or-identify-unused-packages-from-flutter-to-reduce-size-of-the-pro)

clearing out the pubspeck.lock files, .pub-cache folder, `flutter clean` `flutter pub get` everything. There is no reference in any files in my projects to `0.9.20` whatsoever, and all pubspec.yaml files have it pinned:

```
dependencies:
  serverpod_client: ^0.9.8
```

So where is flutter getting 0.9.20 from? or even more importantly how do I just clear it all out?

the weird thing is, if I re-clone it and run `dart pub get` then look at the pubspeck.lock it creates it shows

```
  serverpod_client:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: serverpod_client
      url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
    source: hosted
    version: "0.9.20"
```

even though the pubspec.yaml clearly pins it at `0.9.8` this tells me that the issue isn't in the project or repo or it's cache, but in my actual flutter installation somehow... flutter's cache?

Here's a extended version of the error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
: Error: Type 'ServerpodClientErrorCallback' not found.
../…/protocol/client.dart:72
      ServerpodClientErrorCallback? errorHandler,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
: Error: The non-abstract class 'Consent' is missing implementations for these members:
package:ravencoin_back/…/protocol/consent_class.dart:14
 - SerializableEntity.toJson
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class Consent extends SerializableEntity {
      ^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/j/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/serverpod_serialization-0.9.20/lib/src/serialization.dart:21:11: Context: 'SerializableEntity.toJson' is defined here.
  dynamic toJson();
          ^^^^^^
: Error: The non-abstract class 'ConsentDocument' is missing implementations for these members:
package:ravencoin_back/…/protocol/consent_document_class.dart:14
 - SerializableEntity.toJson
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
```

Comment: Late to the party: I don't think `^0.9.8` pins to `0.9.8`, the caret symbol allows non-breaking versions to be selected [see docs](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal to clean cache run `dart pub cache clean`
to clean packages in project build, `flutter clean`

More info: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache

Comment: this might have worked, but I tried it and had some initial issues, so I just removed dart and flutter from my machine and restinstalled them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65819711/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-flutter-sdk-from-windows https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows